# Trouble While Learning About Java Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, instance

I am having trouble figuring out why my code is not working. I have looked over the code for hours and am sure it is probably a simple syntax error, but I can't identify it.
Main Class File:

```
public class calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        addme addMyNum = new addme(52,54);
        addMyNum.printSum();
    }
}
```

and the class I want to get an instance of:

```
import java.util.*;

public class addme
{

private int firstInt;
private int secondInt;
private int addsum;

    public void addme(int a, int b)
    {

        firstInt = a;
        secondInt = b;

    }

    public int getSum()
    {

        addsum = firstInt + secondInt;
        return addsum;
    }

    public void printSum()
    {

        System.out.println("The sum of " + firstInt + "and " + secondInt     + "is " + getSum());

    }

}
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? Also: no need to have a special member for "addsum", getSum() should just return the value, not store it, I guess. Also, please use traditional CamelCase notation for the class name: `AddMe` instead of `addme`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor don't have a return type. Not even `void`.

Change your constructor declaration from

```
public void addme(int a, int b)
```

To

```
public addme(int a, int b)
```

To learn more about constructor, [visit this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Hope this helps